# What is a good alternative to Ionic Slide-Box on Windows Phone 8 using Cordova?

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework, slide

I'm using Apache Cordova to develop an app. It consists of two pages. I connect these pages using the ion-slide. While everything seems to work just fine on the Android and iOS Versions, sliding just won't work when I debug the app on wp8.

Does anybody know a way out / some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has a different touch model which causes issues with slide.  What I used to get around it was include hammer.js.  Hammer.js handles slide/swipe events on Windows as you would expect.

What you could do is create a hammer.js handler on the container containing the ion-slide.  When a swipe is detected by hammer, you can then call the appropriate event on the container / control itself:

Hammer library:
http://hammerjs.github.io

Here is some code from one of my apps to handle sliding on windows.  It is an app that used jQuery mobile sliding page transitions.  On iOS and Android the JQM swiperight event would work fine when attached to the contentAbout directly, but on Windows I have to create a Hammer object wrapping the content:

```
    var caHammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("contentAbout"));
    caHammer.on("swiperight", function () { $("#imgExitAbout").click(); });
```

Note: This code would work fine on iOS / Android as well so you don't have to have platform specific code based on device.OS